# x86-64 SIMD mechanism to "compare" 8-bit unsigned integers, giving a vector of +1 / 0 / -1 results (signum)?

Tags: simd, avx, avx2, avx512

Let's say I have two unsigned integer (8-bit) packed registers a and b. I'd like to compare them and get back +1 for a > b, 0 for a=b, or -1 for a < b. Alternatively, distance also works (i.e. instead of -1/+1, the actual difference is returned).

What's the SIMD (presumably AVX2) approach for accomplishing this efficiently? I can't use AVX512 but would be good to know if this is an AVX512 feature.

Comment: What are you going to do with that vector of `-1` / `0` / `+1`  results?  You probably need to process it back into two vectors, one for equal or not, one for less than, to use it for masking something else.  (Or subtract if you know your numbers are within +-127 of each other, setting up for `_mm_sign_epi8`?)  Anyway, you probably have to generate a `>` and an `==` vector in the first place as part of something to produce a -1/0/+1 vector, so in most cases just return them both instead of compressing / decompressing.

Comment: (Or with AVX-512, two masks.  AVX-512 adds unsigned integer compare, saving 2 XOR operations to range-shift unsigned to signed for `_mm256_cmpgt_epi8`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a <=> b` for signed bytes would be `_mm256_subs_epi8(a, b)` (subtract using signed saturation).
The result can be normailzed to `-1 / 0 / 1` using `_mm256_sign_epi8(_mm256_set1_epi8(-1), res)`

Unsigned bytes could be "range shifted"<sup>[1]</sup> to signed bytes:

```
const __m256i x80 = _mm256_set1_epi8(-128);
__m256i res = _mm256_subs_epi8(_mm256_xor_si256(a, x80), _mm256_xor_si256(b, x80));
```

---

Absolute difference can be found by

`_mm256_or_si256(_mm256_subs_epu8(a, b), _mm256_subs_epu8(b, a))` or

`_mm256_sub_epi8(_mm256_max_epu8(a, b), _mm256_min_epu8(a, b))`.

---

[1] Range Shifting:

SSE2 (or later) often have instructions for signed integers without any corresponding instruction for unsigned integers (or vice versa).

To convert 8-bit integers between signed and unsigned ranges just add or subtract 128.

```
Signed 8-bit integers have the range -128..127
Unsigned 8-bit integers have the range 0..255
```

A micro-optimization for this conversion is to flip the most significant bit of a lane using XOR. 128 is `0b10000000` (0x80) in two's complement. There is no 9th bit so there is no need for a borrow or carry. Logical ops may run on more execution ports than arithmetic ops, on some architectures. Most SSE2 instructions have destructive two-operand forms so XOR allows the compiler to freely reorder x ^= y into y ^= x, unlike subtraction.

Comment: I thought the part of your answer explaining "range-shifting" by flipping the MSB was good.  It's a useful general concept for beginners to understand, and it's not magic.  (Including the mention of why xor instead of add or sub, since it might run on more ports on some AVX2 CPUs, and add-without-carry is equivalent to add when the only non-zero bit is at the top.)

Comment: Your absolute-different using `or(sub, sub)` needs to be unsigned-saturating subtract, doesn't it?  Which might run on even fewer ports than min/max/sub :/  There is no `sub_epu8` so I assume that was a typo for `subs_epu8`, rather than `sub_epi8`.  On Zen 3/4, min/max/sub run on any port.  `vpsubusb` runs on only 2 ports.  On Intel since Skylake, `vpminub` runs on p01, same as `psubusb`, while `sub` and `or` can each run on any port.  So sub(max,min) is maybe better on AMD, not worse on Intel.  https://uops.info/

Comment: Accepting the answer because it's what I asked. @PeterCordes is correct in terms of answering the underlying question of what I was actually doing by telling me to just use `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8_mask` / `_mm256_cmplt_epi8_mask` / `_mm256_cmpgt_epi8_mask` / directly.

Comment: @Vitali: Note that `_mm256_cmplt_epi8_mask` is AVX-512.  AVX2 compares produce a `__m256i` vector, not a `__mmask32`.  I assume you meant _mm256_cmpgt_epi8` and `cmpeq`.

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 3):

This is surprisingly tedious because unsigned 8 bit integers are not well supported, for example no unsigned comparison. For signed 8 bit, it would be reasonably simple.

Using [Intel intrinsics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html) I came up with this routine:

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

void compare(int8_t* out, const uint8_t* a, const uint8_t* b, ptrdiff_t n)
{
    ptrdiff_t i;
    for(i = 0; i + 32 <= n; i += 32) {
        __m256i ai = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)(a + i));
        __m256i bi = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)(b + i));
        __m256i min_u = _mm256_min_epu8(ai, bi);
        /* Set all bits 1 (== -1) if a <= b */
        __m256i a_le_b = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(min_u, ai);
        /* And the reverse */
        __m256i b_le_a = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(min_u, bi);
        /*
         * Three cases:
         * 1. a == b: Both masks are set. Subtraction results in zero
         * 2. a < b: Left mask is -1, right is 0. Result is -1
         * 3. a > b: Left mask is 0, right is -1. 0 - (-1) == 1
         */
        __m256i result = _mm256_sub_epi8(a_le_b, b_le_a);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)(out + i), result);
    }
    if(n > 32) {
        /* overlapping iteration to deal with trailing elements */
        i = n - 32;
        __m256i ai = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)(a + i));
        __m256i bi = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)(b + i));
        __m256i min_u = _mm256_min_epu8(ai, bi);
        __m256i a_le_b = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(min_u, ai);
        __m256i b_le_a = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(min_u, bi);
        __m256i result = _mm256_sub_epi8(a_le_b, b_le_a);
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)(out + i), result);
    }
    else if(n < 32) {
        /* Scalar loop if entire input is less than 1 vector */
        for(; i < n; ++i) {
            uint8_t ai = a[i], bi = b[i];
            out[i] = (ai >= bi) - (ai <= b);
        }
    }
}
```

The body of the main loop compiles to this:

```
        vmovdqu ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdx+rax]
        vmovdqu ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax]
        vpminub ymm2, ymm0, ymm1
        vpcmpeqb        ymm0, ymm0, ymm2
        vpcmpeqb        ymm1, ymm1, ymm2
        vpsubb  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax], ymm0
```

GCC, when given that scalar loop, comes up with the same solution. But it is very sensitive to the content of the loop. It cannot reduce an if-else-if-else construct (or chained ternary operators) to the same code.

### AVX512

AVX512 makes the code more straightforward. Here is a main loop for AVX512

```cpp
        __m512i ai = _mm512_loadu_si512((const __m512i*)(a + i));
        __m512i bi = _mm512_loadu_si512((const __m512i*)(b + i));
        __mmask64 a_ne_b = _mm512_cmp_epu8_mask(ai, bi, _MM_CMPINT_NE);
        __mmask64 a_gt_b = _mm512_cmp_epu8_mask(bi, ai, _MM_CMPINT_LT);
        /* -1 if a != b */
        __m512i result = _mm512_movm_epi8(a_ne_b);
        /* negate -1 to 1 if a > b */
        result = _mm512_mask_abs_epi8(result, a_gt_b, result);
        _mm512_storeu_si512((__m512i*)(out + i), result);
```

Comment: The OP mentioned interest in AVX-512.  AVX-512 adds unsigned integer compares, e.g. `vpcmpub` `_mm256_cmp_epu8_mask(a, b, _MM_CMPINT_LT)`.  But yes, until then, there's no unsigned compare, only stuff like `min` and `sub` with unsigned saturation.  Otherwise you need to range-shift to signed to set up for `vpcmpgtb`, or `min` / `eq` like you're doing.  (Do we really need `vpblendvb`?  That's a 2-uop instruction on Intel.  I guess probably yes, without `vpternlogd`, it would take at least 2 instructions to replace it.)

Comment: The redundant vector load from GCC is probably https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97366 , which seems to be a GCC8 regression.  For that MCVE, I reported that `-march=haswell` happened to fix it for 128-bit vectors but not 256-bit, similar to how you found `-march` can make a difference here.

Comment: @PeterCordes while making the AVX512 version, I stumbled across a faster AVX2 version and a scalar loop version that GCC correctly compiles to the optimal code. This also removes the bug with the redundant load. I'm not sure the AVX512 version is optimal.

Comment: (+1) Seeing the question, I dashed off this AVX2 code:  `__m256i signum_compare (__m256i a, __m256i b) { __m256i maxab = _mm256_max_epu8 (a, b); __m256i maxa  = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8 (maxab, a); __m256i maxb  = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8 (maxab, b); return _mm256_sub_epi8 (maxb, maxa); }` only to find that it is redundant with this answer ...

Comment: @Homer512: For AVX-512, I don't see anything better than 2x compare plus 2 masked operations (or mov mask to vector which can run on any port on Intel).  But we can simplify the vector constants to just a zero (which is cheapest to generate, no immediate or memory constant needed), or actually avoid them entirely: 2x compare (ne and gt): `vpmovm2b` to get `0` / `-1` for elements that are / aren't equal.  Merge-masked `_mm512_mask_abs_epi8`, or subtract from zero, to negate the elements where we want +1 instead of -1.  (Surprisingly there's no AVX-512 `vpsignb`?).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you rarely actually want or need a vector with + / 0 / - values; using that would probably require decoding it back into two masks or something, so just compare twice to get two masks.  (e.g. `_mm256_min_epu8` / `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8` to get a greater-than or less-than vector, and `cmpeq` on the two inputs directly for an equality vector.)

If you want to use this to conditionally negate or zero another vector of bytes, use  `_mm256_sign_epi8` with the result from aqrit's answer that produces a +/0/- vector.  (Surprisingly there's no AVX-512 `vpsignb`, so you'd need something else in that case.)

If you actually want to conditionally negate some floats or other something, don't multiply by 1.0 or -1.0, just flip the sign bit with XOR.  (And mask with 0 or 0xffffffff, after sign-extending a `vpcmpeqb` result with `vpmovsxbd`).

---

**Since you asked about an AVX-512 version:**

What I said above about not creating a +/0/- vector in the first place goes double for AVX-512; using masking versions of other operations may let you apply a `__mmask64` for nearly free, or with fewer instructions, whatever you actually wanted to do with it.  That said, we can have a look at it:

AVX-512's new unsigned-compare instruction can only compare into a mask register, and materializing that back into a vector of 0 / -1 takes another instruction.  (But at least it's a cheapish instruction, e.g. runs on any execution port on Intel, and doesn't need any vector constant already loaded.)  Before AVX-512, the only SIMD integer compares available are for equality and signed greater-than.  (But there are min/max instructions for signed and unsigned, and both signed and unsigned saturating subtract.)

One way to do it with AVX-512 is still more instructions than aqrit's, but produces a 0 / -1.

- 2x compare (unsigned `ne` and `gt`) to get 2 masks.
- `vpmovm2b` to get `0` / `-1` for elements that are / aren't equal, from the `ne` mask.
- Do a merge-masking `_mm512_mask_abs_epi8` with the `gt` mask to negate the elements where we want +1 instead of -1.

(See Homer512's answer for a C with intrinsics version of this; thanks for writing up what I posted as a suggestion in comments.  And an earlier revision of that answer for a version using merge-masking to blend a `set1(-1)` and a `set1(1)` constant.)

Unfortunately Intel CPUs can only run compare-into-mask on one execution port, so this doesn't have the instruction-level parallelism we'd like.  But as long as the `ne` compare runs first, it's fine, though; we can't use the `gt` mask until the `vpmovm2b` result is ready, so that can happen in parallel with the second compare.

Using 256-bit vector width with AVX-512 (often a good idea unless your whole program heavily uses 512-bit vectors), you could materialize the `ne` vector with AVX2 `vpcmpeqb` and a bitwise NOT (`vpxor` with `-1`), for 2 cycle latency, at the cost of needing a vector constant.  (https://uops.info/).  `-1` is cheap to materialize, though, just a `vpcmpeqd` of a register against itself.

However, for 256-bit vectors, I think Homer's version with 4 AVX2 instructions is probably best, `vpminub` and comparing against that two ways, then subtract the disjoint masks to negate the `-1` elements in one of them at the same time as merging them.  I don't see a way to beat that with AVX-512.  Or better, aqrit's signed-saturating subtract to get a +/0/- vector if you don't need +1/0/-1.